# How do I call my method from another method I have within my class in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm constructing a class that calculates grades of students from a text file. The methods and fields used HAVE to be named exactly as they are written, as this is a school project, and my teacher will take points off if it isn't written exactly as she wants it. Regardless, based on her criteria, she wants me to create a method that calculates the average of an array, and then retrieve that average in another method (seems kind of redundant personally, but like I said, it's what she wants). I've constructed the method, and I reference it in my `getAverage(int studentNum)` method, but it is giving me an error of ".class missing" when I compile it. I'm not sure why to be honest. The solutions that eclipse offers are not what I want to be done, as they suggest I change the parameters of the method, or create an entirely new method, neither of which is what my teacher will want. Here's what I'm working with:

```
public class GradeBook
{
    private final int NUM_STUDENT = 5;
    private final int NUM_TESTS = 4;
    private String[] names = new String[5];
    private char[] grades = new char[5];
    private double[] scores1 = new double[4];
    private double[] scores2 = new double[4];
    private double[] scores3 = new double[4];
    private double[] scores4 = new double[4];
    private double[] scores5 = new double[4];

    public void setName(int studentNum, String name)
    {
        names[studentNum - 1] = name;
    }

    public void setScores(int studentNum, double[] scores)
    {
        if (studentNum == 1)
        {
            copyArray(scores1, scores);
        }

        else if (studentNum == 2)
        {
            copyArray(scores2, scores);
        }

        else if (studentNum == 3)
        {
            copyArray(scores3, scores);
        }

        else if (studentNum == 4)
        {
            copyArray(scores4, scores);
        }

        else
        {
            copyArray(scores5, scores);
        }
    }

    public String getName(int studentNum)
    {
        return names[studentNum - 1];
    }

    public double getAverage(int studentNum)
    {
        double average;

        if (studentNum == 1)
        {
            average = calcAverage(scores1[]);

            return average;
        }

        else if (studentNum == 2)
        {
            return calcAverage(scores2[]);
        }

        else if (studentNum == 3)
        {
            return calcAverage(scores3[]);
        }

        else if (studentNum == 4)
        {
            return calcAverage(scores4[]);
        }

        else
        {
            return calcAverage(scores5[]);
        }
    }

    public char getLetterGrade(int studentNum)
    {
        return grades[studentNum - 1];
    }

    public void copyArray(double[] to, double[] from)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < from.length ; i++)
        {
            from[i] = to[i];
        }
    }

    public double calcAverage(double[] scores)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double average;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < scores.length ; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + scores[i];
            }

        average = sum / scores.length;

        return average;
    }

    public void assignGrade(int studentNum)
    {
            grades[studentNum - 1] = determineGrade(getAverage(studentNum));
    }

    public char determineGrade(double average)
    {
        if (average <= 100 && average >= 90)
        {
            return 'A';
        }

        else if (average <= 89 && average >= 80)
        {
            return 'B';
        }

        else if (average <= 79 && average >= 70)
        {
            return 'C';
        }

        else if (average <= 69 && average >= 60)
        {
            return 'D';
        }

        else 
        {
            return 'F';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's something incredibly easy I'm missing, and I just don't see it. What do you guys think?

Comment: And just as I post this, I realize like an idiot i put [] next to the array names. Guess that's solved then.

Comment: Trust me, that's how programming works. You stare at something forever, then someone else walks up and sees the problem in seconds, or you walk away and when you return to the problem you immediately see what's wrong.

Comment: Yeah.  You only ever see the error **after** you post it, never before.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the [] in your method argument:

```
 average = calcAverage(scores1[]);
```

should be

```
 average = calcAverage(scores1);
```